# Excel - AverageIfs with multiple valid criteria in different collumns

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm trying to get excel to give me the average of multiple objects if they meet a criteria. This is some simple data that is similar to the data I'm actually working with.

```
    Fruit    Amount    Valid?
    Apple    5         Yes
    Apple    7         Yes
    Apple    10        No
    Orange   1         Yes
    Orange   9         No
    Pear     12        Yes
    Pear     7         No
```

What I'm trying right now is

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B:B,A:A,"=Apple",A:A,"=Pear",C:C,"=Yes")
```

What I want is to find the average of rows that are either "Apple" and "Yes" or "Pear" and "Yes". Both pairs are vaild for what I'm doing. The answer I'm expecting is 8 ( (5+7+12)/3 ). Instead, Excel tells me I'm dividing by 0. How should I fix my formula so that it gives me what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=SUM(SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,{"Apple","Pear"},C:C,"Yes"))/SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,{"Apple","Pear"},C:C,"Yes"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`AVERAGIFS` works only when relation between criteria is OR, you can use here `SUMPRODUCT` as it's more flexible:

`=SUMPRODUCT(B2:B8*((A2:A8="Apple")+(A2:A8="Pear"))*(C2:C8="Yes"))/SUMPRODUCT(((A2:A8="Apple")+(A2:A8="Pear"))*(C2:C8="Yes"))`

[image]